# Дописать программу на Python

Tags: python

Дополнить программу, задание таково

> В тексте удалить каждое четное слово, продублировать каждое нечетное слово, заменив все вхождения букв 'д' на букву 'т'. Найти первое число и умножить его значение на 5

У меня получилось только это сообразить, не хватает "Найти первое число  и умножить его значение на 5"

пример ввода "Сегодня 16 декабря 2019 года"

вывод должен быть таким "сеготня 80 текабря гота сеготня 80 текабря гота"

набросок

```
words = input('Строка:').split()
a = (words[::2]) * 2
a = [item.replace("д", "т") for item in a]
print(*a)
```

Comment: Вам нужно продублировать каждое нечетное слово. То есть, очевидно, в исходном тесте нечетные слова должны продублироваться, а вы просто делаете список двойных _четных_ слов.

Answer (score 0):

Если я корректно понял суть задачи, то вот решение

```py
text = input('Введите текст > ')
li = text.split(' ')
res = []
res_1 = []

print('Исходные данные:\n', li)

for i in range(len(li)):
    if i % 2: # слово нечётное (т.к. в python нумерация с нуля, а в предложении с единицы)
        res.append(li[i])

print('Убраны чётные:\n', res)

for i in range(len(res)):
    res_1.append(res[i])
    word = res[i].replace("д", "т")
    res_1.append(word)

res = res_1
del(res_1)
print('Нечётные продублированы, Д -> Т:\n', res)

for i in range(len(res)):
    try:
        k = float(res[i])
        res[i] = k * 5
        break
    except:
        pass

print('Задача выполнена (первое число умножено на 5):\n', res)
```

Входные данные:

```
Мама модулирована радиаторов 30 за раз. Мама - молодец.
```

Результат:

```
Исходные данные:
 ['Мама', 'модулировала', 'радиаторов', '30', 'за', 'раз.', 'Мама', '-', 'молодец.']
Убраны чётные:
 ['модулировала', '30', 'раз.', '-']
Нечётные продублированы, Д -> Т:
 ['модулировала', 'мотулировала', '30', '30', 'раз.', 'раз.', '-', '-']
Задача выполнена (первое число умножено на 5):
 ['модулировала', 'мотулировала', 150.0, '30', 'раз.', 'раз.', '-', '-']
```